# Can a Google Analytics result be passed to a JavaScript function while the user is still on the page?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-bigquery

On my website, users enter some personal information, including ZIP code. This information will be passed to a function that will determine the display of the next page.

The problem is that the function utilizes an underlying statistical model, for which zip codes have too many possible values (~43,000) to be useful. I want to map zip codes to something broader, like [designated market area](https://www.lyonspr.com/latest-nielsen-dma-rankings/) (DMA has around 200 possible values).

But using Google Analytics and BigQuery, I already have the user's DMA before they even enter their ZIP code. Is there a way to access that information while they are still on the page so I can input it to the function?

Comment: you mentioned a statistical model based on customers addresses. Is it something documented in the literature? If so, do you mind sharing its references? Got curious on this one :)

Comment: Alas, the model is a proprietary thing I'm building myself. Suffice to say I'm trying to predict what product people are likely to buy based on what they are first shown on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are wondering if you can use Google Analytics Information in realtime (not quite clear from the question), that will not work - GA does not work in realtime; data processing time is announced as 4 hours for the "premium" version to 24 hours to the standard version, and even if it's often faster you probably do not want to build you business on an undocumented feature that might or might not work as expected.

Also API limits make realtime data retrieval  unfeasible even for smaller sites.

If however you have a stash of precomputed data that can be linked to the current user via an identifier (clientId or similar) it would probably be best to export this to external storage as suggested by Willian Fuks.

Since you mentioned personal data, keep in mind that this must not be stored within Google Analytics as per Google's TOS.

Answer (score 0):

(not quite an answer, more like some thoughts of mine)

I don't think that running queries in BQ for each user you find in production is a good approach.

Costs will increase considerably, performance will not be satisfactory by any means in this scenario and you might start hitting quotas limits for jobs against a single table.

One possibility that might work is having your back-end use some [google analytics client](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/libraries) for retrieving data from G.A. Still, you should check if the [quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/limits-quotas) are appropriate for you.

Another possibility (I suspect this might be the best option) that you may consider for your scenario is using [Google Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview). It might suit your needs quite well; you could have some table from BigQuery being exported to Datastore and have your back-end system query it directly  for the user DMA.